# How to apply animation to gridColums in android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I have created gridView  in xml,I want to access the columns of gridView programatically and apply transistion to each of Columns,instead of eachChildViews.Is it possible to acheive it.

Comment: I am trying to acheive the animation to each column of grid ,instead of wholeView or each ChildView.Please help me in sorting out this,intead of downvote,or tell me the reason of downvote,So that i can change it.

Answer (score 0):

this is way i used to apply transistion ,

```html
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.slide_down);
acctgrid.startAnimation(anim);
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(50);
set.addAnimation(anim);
GridLayoutAnimationController controller1 = new GridLayoutAnimationController(set);
controller1.setRowDelay(0.00f);
controller1.setColumnDelay(0.5f);
((ViewGroup) acctgrid).setLayoutAnimation(controller1);//acctgrid is the gridView
```